# Pushing a notification to million users with ASP.NET core, websocket limits and SignalR performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I have a social-style web-app, and I want to add "live" updates to votes under posts.

At first I thought that a client-side loop with /GET polling the server every few seconds would be an inferior choice, and that all cool kids use websockets or server sent events.

But now I found that websocket would be limited at 65k live connections (even less in practice).

Is there a way to push vote updates to a big number of users realtime?

The app has around ~2 million daily users, so I'd expect 200-300k simultaneous socket connections.

The stack is ASP.NET Core backend hosted on an Ubuntu machine with nginx reverse proxy.

At current state all load is easily handled by a single machine, and I don't really want to add multiple instances just to be able to work with signalR.

May be there is a simple solution that I'm missing out?

Comment: Try to have 1 million HTTP GET requests per second for polling. Would that work? Of course not, a single machine cannot handle 1 million requests per second. I have no clue why you believe this would work - with HTTP, with WebSockets or with any other approach

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, well, that's why I thought that something along the lines of SignalR would be a way to go - because with a million users there wouldn't be a million interactions per second. Only a few interactions per minute per user(max, for active users).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I've seen this article about a million concurrent websocket connections on a single machine, so I thought that may be something similar is doable in ASP.NET Core

https://alexhultman.medium.com/millions-of-active-websockets-with-node-js-7dc575746a01

Comment: "Only a few interactions per minute per user(max, for active users)" -> that's not correct, at all. WebSocket connections need to be alive, they cannot be connected and disconnected from the server as the server sees fit.

Comment: I don't trust that medium at all - where's the actual proof that 1 million connections over the internet were achieved?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, well, that was the reason why the question was asked

Comment: @Anarion I'm curious to learn which solution worked for you, if possible. Just my 5 cents, you mentioned NGINX - it can be limiting the number of concurrent connections to 64K. See the complete discussion here: https://blog.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/